# VC Image Carousel not mobile responsive

Tags: wordpress, themes, visual-composer

using themeforest 'TheGem' theme and Visual composer elements.

The image carousel is not responsive, on small screen its overlap each other, but on big screen its shows 3.

I trying to fix it trough CSS, but not working,
any solution?

```
.vc_carousel-slideline {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.vc_images_carousel {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.vc_images_carousel{max-width: 100%;}
```

No need for:

```
.vc_carousel-slideline{max-width: 100%;}
```